# Can't divide Logged In screens and Logged out ones in React Router + FIrebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm working on the application with React + Firebase. The app requires authentication that users accesses to their own timeline. So I want the app separated between `LoggedIn` screens and `LoggedOut` screens.

In `App.js`, I set up `<Auth />` to the screens require authentication. Like this:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Switch>
              <Auth>
                <Route path="/timeline" component={Timeline} />
              </Auth>
            </Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And added `Auth`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import firebase from "../config/firebase";

class Auth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.user) {
      return (
        <div>{this.state.user ? this.props.children : <Redirect to="/" />}</div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Auth;
```

But it is not working. It has no error message but I can't access any components...

Comment: It doesn't look like you're returning anything when the user is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Router Issue

As mentioned in [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6199) thread, nested Switch components is not the intended way that react-router was designed and should probably be avoided.

I think you have overcomplicated the App component here. I would recommend something more like the below example because your routing logic doesn't need to care about authentication. You can wrap the Timeline component with the Auth component **inside the implementation of Timeline**, and then the router just does the routing, nothing else.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/timeline" component={Timeline} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

An alternative, as mentioned in the linked thread above, is to write your own Switch logic. This might allow you to keep all of the authenticated routes all visible upfront, but you may not want to get into messing around with that.

### You need an 'authenticating' state

As touched on in Soroush's answer, you also have an issue with the state management in the Auth component. At the moment, it goes like this:

1. Component renders with user = false
2. Redirect component is rendered and page redirects to '/'

Do you see how there is never an opportunity to render the child of auth properly for an authenticated user because the initial render will always trigger the redirect? Firebase never has a chance to log the user in before they are redirected.

To fix this, you Auth to load the page into some sort of 'authenticating' state and only redirect the user after you know whether they are logged in or not. Remember, **onAuthStateChanged will only ever be triggered after the initial render**.

Good luck!

Comment: You have a fair point. I have deleted `<Auth />` from Router.

Answer (score 1):

In this case and your authentication structure I recommended to you using programmatically navigate.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Auth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: false,
      authenticating: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (!user) {
        this.props.history.push('/login');
      } else {
        this.setState({ authenticating: false });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{authenticating ? <p>Authenticating...</p> : this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Auth);
```

Comment: @k10a You can support users that answered by giving the upvote to them.